# Is it possible to build the following design in CSS?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors, css-position

I have been trying to build the following design using html/css:

[image]

So far I have been able to achieve the following:

[image]

but now I'm stuck and have not made progress since the last 2 days - so I am looking for help!

Also, is it possible to make this responsive?

To achieve the above I have written the following code:

```css
.contain {
  position: absolute;
  height: 400px;
  width: 700px;
  left: 5%;
}

.hex {
  position: absolute;
  width: 125px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: green;
}

.hex:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  background: green;
}

.hex:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
  background: green;
}

.innerHexagon {
  width: 100px;
  height: 152px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: green;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.innerHexagon:before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  background: green;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.innerHexagon:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
  background: green;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.test {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1600px;
  /*width: 400px;*/
  height: 200px;
  z-index: -1;
  border-right: 0px;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.test:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 140px;
  /*width: 35%;*/
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  left: 1460px;
  /*left: 260px;*/
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: grey;
}

.test:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 140px;
  /*width: 35%;*/
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
  left: 1460px;
  /*left: 260px;*/
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: grey;
}

.text {
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  font-size: xx-large;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: Black;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
</head>

<body>


  <div class="contain">
    <div class="hex">
      <div class="innerHexagon" style="z-index:1">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    </div>
    <div class="hex" style="left: 500px">
      <div class="innerHexagon" style="z-index:1">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hex" style="left: 1000px">
      <div class="innerHexagon" style="z-index:1">

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what if you made it into three sections of grey with a white border and overlap them

Comment: You might be better off doing this, at least partially, with SVG.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with this solution for those white strips. I have added `span` element inside `.hex` div for the purpose and added styles at the end of your original styles. As for the responsive part, you need to elaborate the details on how you want the design to behave on different screens so we may be able to help that way.

```css
.contain {
    position: absolute;
    height: 400px;
    width: 700px;
    left: 5%;
  }
  
  .hex {
    position: absolute;
    width: 125px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: green;
  }
  
  .hex:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 25px;
    transform: rotate(60deg);
    background: green;
  }
  
  .hex:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 25px;
    transform: rotate(-60deg);
    background: green;
  }
  
  .innerHexagon {
    width: 100px;
    height: 152px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: green;
    border-top: 2px solid white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }
  
  .innerHexagon:before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(60deg);
    background: green;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-top: 2px solid white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  }
  
  .innerHexagon:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(-60deg);
    background: green;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-top: 2px solid white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  }
  
  .test {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1600px;
    /*width: 400px;*/
    height: 200px;
    z-index: -1;
    border-right: 0px;
    background: grey;
    border-radius: 30px;
  }
  
  .test:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 140px;
    /*width: 35%;*/
    height: 100%;
    transform: rotate(60deg);
    left: 1460px;
    /*left: 260px;*/
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: grey;
  }
  
  .test:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 140px;
    /*width: 35%;*/
    height: 100%;
    transform: rotate(-60deg);
    left: 1460px;
    /*left: 260px;*/
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: grey;
  }
  
  .text {
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    font-size: xx-large;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: Black;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
  }


  /* new styles added */
.white-strip::after, .white-strip::before {
    content: '';
    height: 115px;
    width: 50px;
    background: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    border-right: 5px solid #ffffff;
    left: -140px;
}

.white-strip::after {
    bottom: 4px;
    transform: rotate(25deg);
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.white-strip::before  {
    top: 4px;
    transform: rotate(-25deg);
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="contain">
        <div class="test"></div>

        <div class="hex">
          <div class="innerHexagon" style="z-index:1"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="hex" style="left: 500px">
            <span class="white-strip"></span> <!-- added -->
            <div class="innerHexagon" style="z-index:1">   </div>
        </div>

        <div class="hex" style="left: 1000px">
            <span class="white-strip"></span> <!-- added -->
            <div class="innerHexagon" style="z-index:1"></div>
        </div>
    
      </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```